# Session Aborted in Shiny

Tags: r, shiny, shiny-server

I wrote a couple of ui.r and server.r codes and when I run, the package displays an aborted message saying:

> R session Aborted ,R encounter a fatal error, The session was terminated.

the codes are

```
library(shiny)
shinyUI(fluidPage (

titlePanel(title="wow my first App"),
sidebarLayout(
sidebarPanel("this is the sidebar panel"),
mainPanel("This is the main Panel text, output displayed here")
)

)

)
```

and

```
library(shiny)
shinyServer(
function(input,output)
{

}

)
```

Can u please help me out? I am using R 3.1.3 at Window Vista

Comment: This can happen if the "Rcpp" package is outdated. Suggest updating all packages starting with that one, if you have not done so alread.

Answer (score 1):

First Run below script then run the shiny app,it will run.

update.packages(ask = FALSE, checkBuilt = TRUE)