# Why are all errors now fatal errors?

Tags: r, rstudio

Seemingly after updating nothing, suddenly I now get a fatal error ("R encountered a fatal error") for *any* error in RStudio. Very strange that this has come out of no where and now affects all projects and RStudio sessions.

I have no idea how this has happened and I can't debug anything now, RStudio just crashes every time there is something to debug.

I tried upgrading R and RStudio and downgrading, but the issue persists.

I am on an Intel Mac.

Any ideas how I can resolve this?

Edit: I think this is only when I'm using Shiny / launching a Shiny app in the browser. Even clicking "Stop" in RStudio to close a Shiny app creates the fatal error. Before, it would just kill the app (but not the entire R session).

I've tried updating packages (`update.packages(ask = FALSE, checkBuilt = TRUE))` as per [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28999990/session-aborted-in-shiny) post.

Edit 2:

The RStudio log shows this error:

> 2022-09-15T12:14:07.241348Z [rdesktop] ERROR Main window closed
> unexpectedly; LOGGED FROM: auto
> rstudio::desktop::MainWindow::closeEvent(QCloseEvent *)::(anonymous
> class)::operator()(QVariant) const
> src/cpp/desktop/DesktopMainWindow.cpp:524 2023-03-21T19:32:46.342Z
> ERROR connect ENOENT rstudio

Comment: In RStudio - you may get some insight by going to Help > Diagnostics > Show Log Files

Comment: Added console log!

Comment: Honestly not sure what's causing that but looks like something got corrupted. ENOENT mean Error No Entity. My best guess at the moment is you're missing a file(s) somewhere or your paths.

Comment: It's absolute hell on earth. I've tried installing and reinstalling R and RStudio, different versions, updating all packages etc. It's horrible.

Comment: Yikes - that stuff is always the worst to deal with. I wonder if this would help https://github.com/r-lib/pkgdown/issues/825 . Maybe you don't have pandoc installed or it is corrupted?

Comment: Thank you! Pandoc is bundled with RStudio (https://bookdown.org/yihui/rmarkdown-cookbook/install-pandoc.html). Not sure it is a good idea to try and get it working myself outside.

Comment: @Jamie solved it! Thank you for your encouragement.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found it, finally! This was really obscure. I noticed on opening a new session (but not project) I would get two warnings:

> Warning: namespace 'rstan' is not available and has been replaced by
> .GlobalEnv when processing object 'objectname'
>
> Warning: namespace 'brms' is not available and has been replaced by
> .GlobalEnv when processing object 'objectname'

I reinstalled these packages and now the issue has stopped!